# delete lines in a csv file older than 7 days

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I have a csv that I need to remove all lines that are older than 7 days.  This is the format of the csv

```
Person ID  VIP  CS  SS  LT  FTLT  PS  Modified Datestamp
T001028    1    1   1   0   0     0   05-07-2013
T001250    1    1   1   0   0     0   08-05-2012
T001261    1    1   1   0   0     1   04-04-2013
T001345    1    1   1   0   0     0   04-03-2013
T078503    1    1   1   0   0     0   04-03-2013
T079819    1    1   1   0   0     1   3/22/2013
T080119    1    1   1   0   0     1   04-02-2013
T090574    1    1   1   0   0     0   11/15/2012
T091106    1    1   1   0   0     1   3/22/2013
```

The format of the column Modified Date is MM/DD/YYYY - Any Ideas.... be looking to execute something on a RedHat 5 linux box.

Comment: Why do some contain dash separators, and some slashes? What is actually being used?

Comment: Unfortunatley this is how the csv comes to us, some records with - seperating the date some with /

Comment: Your data looks whitespace-separated, not comma-separated. CSV stands for comma-separated values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using `tail`, `date -d ...`, `awk`, and just the functionality of Bash.

```
tail -n+2 file.csv | {
  while read line ; do
    tmstmp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}');
    [ $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) )) -lt $(( 60*60*24*7 )) ] && echo "$line";
  done;
}
```

#### How it works?

The above parses the lines from a file, `file.csv`, and get's the 8th column (the date), and then calculates the delta between the number of seconds since epoch for now and the parsed date. If they're less then 7 days worth of seconds then the line get's printed.

#### Debugging

You can put this line in to debug what's going on. Put it just after the `tmpstmp=...` line:

```
echo "TMSTMP: $tmstmp" "TMDELTA: $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) ))" "TMWINDOW: $(( 60*60*24*7 ))"
```

#### Example

For simplicity I put the above into a script and called it `rprttime.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -n+2 file.csv | {
  while read line ; do
    tmstmp=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}');
    echo "TMSTMP: $tmstmp" "TMDELTA: $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) ))" "TMWINDOW: $(( 60*60*24*7 ))"
    [ $(( $(date -d "now" +%s) - $(date -d "$tmstmp" +%s) )) -lt $(( 60*60*24*7 )) ] && echo "$line";
  done;
}
```

Now when we run it:

```
$ ./rprttime.bash
TMSTMP: 05/07/2013 TMDELTA: 5157421 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 08/05/2012 TMDELTA: 28917421 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 04/04/2013 TMDELTA: 8008621 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 04/03/2013 TMDELTA: 8095021 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 04/03/2013 TMDELTA: 8095021 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 3/22/2013 TMDELTA: 9131821 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 04/02/2013 TMDELTA: 8181421 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 11/15/2012 TMDELTA: 20101021 TMWINDOW: 604800
TMSTMP: 3/22/2013 TMDELTA: 9131821 TMWINDOW: 604800
```

If you change the window of time from 7 days to say 60 days and disable the debugging line, you'll see some of the lines getting printed:

```
$ date
Fri Jul  5 16:49:19 EDT 2013

$ ./rprttime.bash
T001028    1    1   1   0   0     0   05/07/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Yet another answer with limited forks

As there is a lot of **forks** to whipe out, there is a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way for doing this using `sed` and only 1 fork to `/bin/date`:

```
sedstr=""
{
    i=1;
    read now;
    while read line;do
        ((i++));
        [ $(( (now-line) /86400 )) -gt 143 ] && sedstr="${i}d;$sedstr"
      done
}< <(
    sed -ne $'s/^.*[ \t,]//g;y|-|/|;/[0-9]$/p;1inow' < file.tsv |
        date -f - +%s
)
sed -e "$sedstr" < file.tsv
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp
T001028     1   1   1   0   0   0   05-07-2013
T001261     1   1   1   0   0   1   04-04-2013
T001345     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
T078503     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
```

The last `sed` command could be used with `-i` for inplace modification instead of output to console.

```
echo $sedstr 
10d;9d;8d;7d;3d;

sed -e $sedstr -i file.tsv 
cat file.tsv 
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp
T001028     1   1   1   0   0   0   05-07-2013
T001261     1   1   1   0   0   1   04-04-2013
T001345     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
T078503     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
```

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the date up to which the lines shall be ignored before you call awk then you can do this:

```
awk -v cmpdate=20130628 '{line=$0; dateval=$8;FS="/"; $0=dateval; 
  thisdate=$3*10000+$1*100+$2; if (thisdate>cmpdate) print line; FS=" ";}' file
```

**Edit 1:**

Reset `FS` to its original value at the end. I tested my code with just one line of input so that it didn't make a difference...

Comment: That's some neckbeard vomit right there. Nice.

Comment: @MelBoyce what is "neckbeard vomit"? It doesn't sound very complimentary.

Comment: Oh, it's very complimentary. We should all aspire to that level of tool voodoo.

Comment: @MelBoyce is that your term or have you heard it used in a positive way before? Have a look at my question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118514/25030).

Comment: @terdon - The accepted answer on english.stackexchange.com is pretty much right. A neckbeard (at least in the context used by my peers) is an older, wiser UNIX guru (usually someone who started using UNIX back in the sixties or seventies) and the context for "vomit" in this case refers to the unreadability, but succinctness of the answer.

Comment: @MelBoyce Ah, I see, not a use of "vomit" to mean "good" the way "sick" can then. Thanks, its always good to extend one's vocabulary :).

Comment: @terdon - Pretty sure he's messing with you. Please don't use "neckbeard vomit" as a compliment.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I had no intention of doing so. I just wanted to understand where the term was coming from and what the intended meaning was. Also, if you want to discuss this, please do so in [the relevant ELU.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118514/25030) question and not here. Let's not spam Hauke's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As there seem not to be a better answer than this (all purposed solution will do one fork to `/bin/date` for **each** lines), there is a clean and efficient way to do the job,but using perl.

Question stand for *csv* (coma separated value) and present *tsv* (tab sep vals), so my script will work for any kind of *tab*, *coma* or *space* separated values (just look for last field).

No fork, `perl` will do the date parsing himself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Date::Parse;

my $day=7;
if ($ARGV[0] && $ARGV[0] > 0) { $day=$ARGV[0]; shift; };

while (<>) {
    my @fields=split(/[ \t,]/);
    print if /^Person/ || str2time($fields[$#fields]) > time()-$day*86400;
};
```

U could run this without argument, as a *filter* or with filename as argument:

```
./dropOlderThan.pl < file.tsv
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp

./dropOlderThan.pl file.tsv
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp
```

If first argument is a number, they will be interpreted as number of day to keep in output:

```
./dropOlderThan.pl 144 file.tsv
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp
T001028     1   1   1   0   0   0   05-07-2013
T001261     1   1   1   0   0   1   04-04-2013
T001345     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
T078503     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
```

And finally, if you want to modify the file in place:

```
perl -i dropOlderThan.pl 144 file.tsv 
cat file.tsv 
Person ID   VIP CS  SS  LT  FTLT    PS  Modified Datestamp
T001028     1   1   1   0   0   0   05-07-2013
T001261     1   1   1   0   0   1   04-04-2013
T001345     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
T078503     1   1   1   0   0   0   04-03-2013
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with Perl (run this from the terminal) :

```perl
$ perl -lane 'BEGIN{$date=`date +%s`; chomp($date)}    
            if($.==1){print}                         
            else{
                 $F[$#F]=~s/-/\//g; 
                 $fdate=`date -d "$F[$#F]" +%s`;     
                 chomp($fdate);                      
            print if $date-$fdate<604800;     
          }' file.csv
```

This script works by calculating today's date in [seconds since the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then translating the date of each line to the same format, subtracting it from today's date and printing only if it is less than 7 days old (7*24*60*60=604800).

NOTES

- The script works with seconds, this may be a bit too precise for what you had in mind. Let me know if so, and I will modify it to work at the level of days instead.
- I am also converting `MM-DD-YYYY` to `MM/DD/YYYY`on the fly, this may not be necessary if your input file is homogeneously formatted but it is needed for the example you have posted.